# How to test for undefined pagination variable in Postman request body upon first iteration?

Tags: api, postman

New to API Integration and Postman. Trying to understand a basic concept. I'm using a NextPage environment variable in the request body to get records beyond a 500 limit. First iteration is undefined. After initial it's okay. How and in what section of Postman do I test for undefined to keep it from throwing variable is undefined error? Thanks!

Request Body
{"Include": ["All"], "Filter":["Orderable","Finished", "InStock", "BestSeller"], "NextPage": "{{NextPage}}"}

Request Test

let response=pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("NextPage", response.NextPage);

I'm assuming I need to set NextPage to something in the Pre-req but, I'm not sure what it gets set to and how to test when it's undefined.

Comment: Looks like the first request needs to be a Get, and the subsequent requests Post. If I do this it gets the NextPage variable on first request and posts it on following requests getting the next page of records without error. There's probably a better way I'm unaware of.

Comment: where are you getting the error , please add screenshot or more information

Comment: There's not much else to show. The issue is the request body has a variable that isn't defined until after the first response. Using Get on the first run, and Post there after works but it seems there's a way to test for undefined before the first request is sent. So far everytime I test an undefined variable it throws an error saying the variable is undefined. No kidding. That's why I'm testing it. Lol